# Client based routing on a gateway

Tags: debian, iptables, routing, openvpn

I have a network gateway (Debian) with two interfaces: eth0 and tun0. In general all traffic from all clients is routed through tun0.

I would like to change that in the following way:

- client a‘s traffic is routed only through eth0
- client b‘s traffic is routed only through tun0
- all other clients are routed through tun0 if existent and through eth0 is tun0 is not available

I am currently using iptables to route specific traffic originating from the gateway itself and have no clue how I can change it to „client based“-routing.

--- Update ---

- Client A will have a static IP address
- Client B will have a static IP address
- eth0 has a dynamic IP address
- tun0 has a dynamic IP address

Comment: If you want to route based on source IP address (is that what you mean by "client based"?) then you need *policy routing*; start with `man ip rule`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned by user Ferenc, policy routing is probably the best solution.

Take a look at `ip rule`, it will typically look like this:

```
# ip rule
0:      from all lookup local 
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

This is a sorted list of rule priorities followed by the rule specification. `local`, `main` and `default` are the routing tables to look at. To see a specific routing table run `ip route show table <table>` or in short `ip r s t <table>`.

In order to route different source IPs to different targets or over different devices we will need separate routing *tables* and routing *rules* for jumping into these tables.

Lets assume we want to have a special route for IP 10.0.0.42 and a special route for net 10.0.0.128/25. We have to create two additional *rules* and two additional *tables*, the order doesn't matter. Let's create the rules. Example:

```
# ip rule add from 10.0.0.42 lookup 300 prio 5
# ip rule add from 10.0.0.128/25 lookup 301 prio 6
```

Let's take a look at them:

```
# ip rule
0:  from all lookup local 
5:  from 10.0.0.42 lookup 300 
6:  from 10.0.0.128/25 lookup 301
32766:  from all lookup main 
32767:  from all lookup default
```

`300` and `301` are our table names (tables usually are just numbers but can be given names, too, by adding them to `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`). The rest should be self-explanatory.

Now we need to fill these tables. Example:

```
# ip route add default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1 table 300
# ip route add 192.168.178.0/24 dev eth2 table 301
```

Let's take a look at them:

```
# ip route show table 300
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth1 scope link 
# ip route show table 301
192.168.178.0/24 dev eth2 scope link
```

As you can see it is possible to add any route you like. The system from address 10.0.0.42 will now get routed via 10.0.0.1 over eth1. Systems from network 10.0.0.128/25 will now get routed via eth2 *if* their destination address is inside network 192.168.178.0/24.

If no route matches from your special routing tables the next routing rule gets evaluated. For example if systems from network 10.0.0.128/25 don't want to route to 192.168.178.0/24 then they fall back to the main table.

If you want to remove any rule then just replace `add` with `del`. The routing tables will exist until you have removed all of their routes, e.g. by running `ip route flush table <table>`. If you want to see *all* routing rules then simply run `ip route show table all`.

Routing rules are very flexible, you can use various other selectors such as incoming/outgoing interfaces, source/dest ports and protocols. See `man ip rule` for details.

Take care to not lock yourself out when editing routes and rules via SSH.