# Debian: 2 interfaces, 2 gateways

Tags: debian, networking, bridge

**My goal is**: to have two network interfaces on a system `eth0` and `tap0`, and both of them have a working internet connection. I should be able to selectively  bind services/programs in both.

**Apache Example**: I want to create the following vhosts:

- **`site1.example.com`** binded to `85.xxx.49.100` available at `eth0`
- **`site2.example.com`** binded to `89.xxx.xxx.5` available at `tap0`
- **`site3.example.com`** binded to `89.xxx.xxx.4` available at `tap0`

Programs in the system should communicate with the outside world using `eth0` by default **BUT** also be able to bind to IPs at `tap0` (if needed) and use them for incoming and outgoing traffic. **Example**: I should be able to run `speedtest-cli --source="85.xxx.49.100"` (IP at `eth0`) and `speedtest-cli --source="89.xxx.xxx.4"` (IP at `tap0`).

---

I've a Debian machine that has physical Ethernet interface `eth0`, this interface gets and IP, gateway and DNS server from a DHCPd server. The `/etc/network/interfaces` has:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
no-auto-down eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

When the network gets online my routing table looks like this:

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         85.xxx.xxx.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
85.xxx.49.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
link-local      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
```

Now, I added a `tap` device (using OpenVPN) to this machines. The **OpenVPN client** and the **server do not assign any IP addresses**. The idea is to have just layer 2 there between the machines. Here is the OpenVPN server configuration:

```
local 89.xxx.xxx.8
port xxxx
proto udp
dev tap0
mode server
tls-server
user nobody
group nogroup
tls-version-min 1.2
auth SHA512
tls-cipher TLS-DHE-RSA-WITH-AES-256-GCM-SHA384
script-security 1
client-to-client
keepalive 10 60
compress
max-clients 10
cipher AES-256-CBC
persist-key
persist-tun
```

The network on the server is configured as:

**10-static-eth0.network**

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
Bridge=br0
```

**25-br0.netdev**

```
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge
```

**25-br0.network**

```
[Match]
Name=br0

[Network]
DHCP=no
Address=89.xxx.xxx.8/24
Address=89.xxx.xxx.7/24
Address=89.xxx.xxx.6/24
Gateway=89.xxx.xxx.1

DNS=1.1.1.1
DNS=8.8.8.8
```

**30-tap.network**

```
[Match]
Name=tap0

[Network]
Bridge=br0
```

After starting OpenVPN any Ethernet frames going into the `tap0` device on the client to come out at `br0` of the server. In theory this would **mean** I can **assign any IP address reserved for the server to the `tap0` device on the client**. I tried to add an IP to the client's `tap` device:

```
ip addr add 89.xxx.xxx.5/24 broadcast 89.xxx.xxx.255 dev tap0
ip link set tap0 up
route add default gw 89.xxx.xxx.1 metric 200
ip route add 89.xxx.xxx.8 via 85.xxx.xxx.1 dev eth0
```

The IP is there and I'm able to ping google with both: `ping -I eth0 google.com` and `ping -I tap0 google.com`, however I can't, for instance, use `wget` with the source set as `89.xxx.xxx.5` - it just times out.

How should I proceed? Thank you.

Comment: You seem to want two default routes. You can't do that: the "default" route is the (single) route that is used _by default_ when there are no other explicit routing instructions.

Comment: @roaima I get the point... but... how am I able to have a default route to be used by the system and most programs and then have 2 specific programs binded to the other IP so they can communicate with clients using that other IP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Client based routing on a gateway](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492424/client-based-routing-on-a-gateway)

Comment: @roaima that's absolutely not what I'm looking for. I've updated my answer to make this more clear.

Comment: You've got lots of detail but it's still not clear (to me) what problem you're trying to solve. If you've got a solution (as evidenced by you posting an answer) that's great; I'm glad you found something that works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.netfilter.html I got creative with `iptables` and `iproute2` and this seems to work for my use case:

1. Start OpenVPN client to make sure the `tap0` is created and L2 is working;
2. Assign `89.xxx.xxx.5` to the device and set the link up:

```
ip addr add 89.xxx.xxx.5/24 broadcast 89.xxx.xxx.255 dev tap0
ip link set tap0 up
```

3. Create a secondary routing table and a marker to be used with the IP's at `tap0` and add the routes:

```
echo "1 BRIDGESERVER" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

ip route add default via 89.xxx.xxx.1 dev tap0 table BRIDGESERVER

ip route add 89.xxx.xxx.8 via 85.xxx.xxx.1 dev eth0 # xxx.8 is the VPN server  and xxx.1 is the local gateway
ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 89.xxx.xxx.1 dev tap0 table BRIDGESERVER
ip route add 128.0.0.0/1 via 89.xxx.xxx.1 dev tap0 table BRIDGESERVER

ip route show table BRIDGESERVER
ip rule add from all fwmark 0x1 lookup BRIDGESERVER
```

4. Use `iptables` to mark all tcp/udp traffic comming from / to our assigned IP (`89.xxx.xxx.5`) so it wil use the secondary routing table / default gateway:

```
iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -p tcp --destination 89.xxx.xxx.5 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -p tcp --source 89.xxx.xxx.5 -j MARK --set-mark 1

iptables -t mangle -I PREROUTING -p udp --destination 89.xxx.xxx.5 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -p udp --source 89.xxx.xxx.5 -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

**Some tests**:

- Without setting a source IP to bind to - will default to IPs at `eth0`:

```
speedtest
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from xyz (85.xxx.49.100)...
```

- Binding to the IP previously assigned to `tap0`:

```
speedtest --source=89.xxx.xxx.5
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from cpv (89.xxx.xxx.5)...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various assumptions how networking works in this question that don't match reality.

> I added a tap device to this machines that is bridged to the network of a remote server.

You can't "bridge a tap device to a network of a remote server". A tap device is a means of letting some kind of application control a network interface. Without an application that is connected to that tap device, the tap device does exactly nothing.

> From my understanding any ethernet frames going into the `tap` device on the Debian machine should come out on the bridge `br0` of the server.

No.

What you can do is use some sort of tunnel (OpenVPN, tinc, wirdeguard; there's lots of options). This tunnel will create one network interface on your debian machine (tap or other), and one network interface on the server. *On the server*, you can bridge this device to the outward facing network interface. *On the debian machine*, you can give this device two IP addresses (`89.xxx.xxx.5` and `89.xxx.xxx.6`), assuming the outward facing network *on the server* could also be assigned those.

Don't use two default routes. Use a single default route, and bind your apache to each of the three internet address on the Debian machine.

**Edit**

You already have a working solution as detailed in the other answer, but for reference:

- [iroute in OpenVPN](http://backreference.org/2009/11/15/openvpn-and-iroute/) to route subnets
- [tinc bridging](https://www.tinc-vpn.org/examples/bridging/) does what you wanted originally out of the box

Comment: "What you can do is use some sort of tunnel (OpenVPN" => this is what I've done, the tap on the server is created by OpenVPN and on the client as well. As I decribed it doesn't work properly because I can't tell the debian client how to route traffic of programs binded to `89.xxx.xxx.5` etc. Even ping doesn't work properly.

Comment: Then please edit your question and indicate how you have set up your OpenVPN; there's nothing in the question about it, it doesn't even mention OpenVPN. And while such kind of routing can be done with OpenVPN, it's a real headache, and I'd suggest using some other kind of method if possible.

Comment: I've just updated with a more clear explanation and the OpenVPN server config. What other methods do you suggest? I'm not really interested in have the traffic encrypted it could be in the clear, I really just want to assign the IP addresses reverved for the server on debian machine for some services. Using a reverse proxy doesn't really fit my needs because I can't have ougoing traffic with those IPs.